# Proof involving inductive sets

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

I am given the problem:

> If $X$ is an inductive set, then the set $\{x\in X: x\notin x \wedge x \text{ is transitive} \} = S$ is inductive.

We are given the definition

> $T$ is transitive if $x \in T$ implies $x \subset T$

$\emptyset \in S$ since $\emptyset \in X$, $\emptyset \notin \emptyset$, and $\emptyset$ is transitive.

Now let $x \in S$. Clearly, $x \cup \{x\}$ must be in $X$ by assumption. So, if we take some $y \in x\cup\{x\}$, then $y = x$ or $y\in x$. If it's the first case, then use the fact that $x$ is itself transitive so $y \subset x$. If it's the later, then $y = x \subset x\cup \{x\}$. Therefore $x \cup \{x\}$ is transitive.

So we clearly have $x\cup\{x\} \neq x$ since $x \notin x$. Now assume $x\cup\{x\} =y$ for some $y\in x$. Since $x$ is transitive, $y\subset x$. But again, $x\cup\{x\}$ cannot be a subset since this inclusion $x \subset x\cup\{x\}$ is proper. Therefore, $x \cup \{x\}$ is not equal to any element in $x \cup\{x\}$ and is not an element.

Therefore, we showed that if $x \in S$, $x\cup\{x\}$ will also be in $S$. Hence, $S$ is inductive.

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: I don't see anything you've missed.

Comment: @RobertShore great, thank you. I've had a hard time getting this down, so I wanted to get it checked.

Comment: "$y=x$ or $yin x$. If it's the first case ..." - I suppose you swapped first/second in this argument

Comment: You deleted this same question, and then reposted. **Why?** That is frowned upon. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3252658/proof-involving-inductive-sets?noredirect=1#comment6689070_3252658

Comment: @ArturoMagidin because my proof was incoherent! I needed to reflect and fix it.

Comment: @GoodMorningCaptain: That's what the **edit** button is for. Don't delete-repost, *edit*.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin then I'll do so in the future. thanks for letting know about the proper etiquette!